# get date from datepicker in default format and convert to another format in jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have these elements on the page (a hidden field next to a simple textbox):

```
<input id="start_date" type="text">

<input id="start_date_hidden" type="hidden">
```

I apply datePicker to textbox I wrote this :

```
$("#start_date").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD dd MM yy'   
});
```

Now I want after select a date convert selected date to another format and set into hidden field. for that i wrote this :

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD dd MM yy',
                onSelect: function ( dateText,  inst) {
                    val =   $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val()

                    $(this).next().val(val)
                }
            });
```

But this does not work and set date with same format of textbox.

How Can I do that ?

Comment: Just to be sure before posting an answer: You are using this [jquery date plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) ?

Comment: Your text and code refer to both `datepicker`, and `datetimepicker`.  What are you using?

Comment: Yes , I am using jquery date plugin and it was a typo.sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Datepicker supports an "alt" field and format where you can save the selected date in another format.

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD dd MM yy',
    altFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    altField: "#start_date_hidden"
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField